# Error when pressing button to switch views

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-intent

When pressing a button to switch intents, I get the Chicago Train Tracker has stopped unexpectedly and a logcat of:

```
09-02 19:54:15.745: D/AndroidRuntime(20681): Shutting down VM
09-02 19:54:15.745: W/dalvikvm(20681): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ab6700)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class com.dev.chicagotraintracker.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'Button'
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sendMessage [class android.view.View]
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
09-02 19:54:15.755: E/AndroidRuntime(20681):    ... 11 more
09-02 19:54:16.875: I/Process(20681): Sending signal. PID: 20681 SIG: 9
```

My code is:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.dev.chicagotraintracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}


    public void login_Click(View v) {;
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screenmap.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

;

}
```

Screenmap.java

```
package com.dev.chicagotraintracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class Screenmap extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screenmap);
}}
```

and AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dev.chicagotraintracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.dev.chicagotraintracker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Screenmap" android:label="Screenmap"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your XML too activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception seems to be clear:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class com.dev.chicagotraintracker.MainActivity `

The error is because you have mentioned `android:onClick="sendMessage"` in the `ImageButton` defined in `activity_main.xml`, but you don't have any `sendMessage()` function in your `MainActivity`. That is why you are getting the error . You need to define that function in the `MainActivity` which tell it what should happen when the `ImageButton` is clicked. So the code which should execute on button click, inside that function.

Eg: If you want to start a new activity on Button click do something like:

```
public void sendMessage(View v){ 

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screenmap.class);   
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 

}
```

Put this piece of code outside the `onCreate()` and as a different function.

Comment: Okay, that prevented any errors. However, the button no longer does anything when being pressed. Could this be due to no onClickListener?

Comment: Whatever you want it to do, you need to post that code inside the `sendMessage()` function. If you are using `onCLickListener` on the `ImageButton` then you might not need `android:onClick="sendMessage"`

Comment: So, if you want to start a new activity do something like: `private void sendMessage(){ Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screenmap.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
 }`

Comment: @ShobhitPuri sorry friend but `private` will not work it must be `public`

Answer (score 1):

you must implement a method in your activity with name `sendMessage` as your `logcat` says

something like this in Your `MainActivity.java`

```
public void sendMessage(View)
{
\\ do your stuff
}
```

and also your **next error** would be because of this

```
 <activity android:name="Screenmap" android:label="Screenmap"></activity>
```

it should be like this

```
 <activity android:name=".Screenmap" android:label="Screenmap"></activity>
```

### OR

```
<activity android:name="com.dev.chicagotraintracker.Screenmap" android:label="Screenmap">
</activity>
```

do not forget `android:name=".Screenmap"` "." before activity name that makes full path of class

Comment: That makes sense! However, when inserting that code, it says that void is an invalid type for the variable sendMessage.

Comment: void is not a variable its return type

Comment: Thank you for your help! Works now!

Answer (score 0):

Your activity_main.xml specifies that when the ImageButton is clicked, it should call the `sendMessage` method, however, you have not created a sentMessage method in your activity.

When you implement the method as `public void sendMessage(View view){ // code }` in your main activity, it's also important to note that the `View` parameter is a reference to the ImageButton that was clicked.